# Logic Equivalences

Tags: logic

I am having trouble finding the logical equivalence to $\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$. I have tried factoring out the negation and going from their but it is not working out. Any ideas on how to g about doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for *all* things equivalent to it? [there are several such.]

Comment: While I'm not completely familiar with doing operations in logic, $\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$ is the contrapositive (and thus logically equivalent) to $Q \Rightarrow P$. That's one possible logical equivalence, but there are others. So the key point would be to give use the appropriate context - are you seeking a specific kind of equivalence? What have you tried, and what exactly are you seeking?

Comment: I am trying to prove that P → Q is not the same as ¬P → ¬Q

Comment: Can you use truth tables?  $P \to Q$ will be true if $P$ is false but  $Q$ is true.  And $P\to Q$ will definitely be false if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.  $\lnot P \to \lnot Q$ will be the exact opposite.  However $Q\to P$ and $\lnot P \to \lnot Q$ will have the same truth values in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

eIt depends on the rules, but $A \Rightarrow B$ is normally defined as $\neg A \lor B$. Then
$$
\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q \equiv (\neg \neg P) \lor \neg Q \equiv 
P \lor \neg Q \equiv Q \Rightarrow P
$$
All those espressions are logically equivalent.

If you want to prove that $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$ are *not* equivalent you can just look at a counterexample, e.g. if $P$ is false and $Q$ is true then $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true, but $\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$ is false.